# SQL Select line with most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.

- Purchase Orders(PURCHASE_ORDER)
- Purchase Order Lines(PURC_ORDER_LINE)

I need the price and currency for a specific part and I also need the row returned to be the latest record in the database.

I figure since I want the latest record I need to select the max(date) the only issue is that since I need the 'group by', my results get grouped and it doesn't just return the single row with the latest date and it's price and currency.

```
   SELECT MAX(PURC_ORDER_LINE.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE) AS 'Latest Order', 
   UNIT_PRICE, 
   PURCHASE_ORDER.CURRENCY_ID
   FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE
   LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER
   ON PURC_ORDER_LINE.PURC_ORDER_ID = PURCHASE_ORDER.ID
   WHERE PART_ID = 'some part'
   GROUP BY UNIT_PRICE, PURCHASE_ORDER.CURRENCY_ID
```

Results:

```
Latest Order UNIT_PRICE     CURRENCY_ID
2015-01-20      20              CHF
2015-04-06      30              CHF
2012-02-23      40              USD
2012-02-17      50              USD
2011-12-08      20              USD
```

What I'm trying to get

```
UNIT_PRICE    CURRENCY_ID
30              CHF
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and the query that you have been using.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, why don't you just use an ORDER BY clause on your date column?

Comment: could I then just have it return the first row?

Comment: I've also added my select and sample data

Comment: And if there are several orders from the most recent date?

Comment: Since I'm specifying a specific part there should only be one, the database won't have separate orders for the same part on the same day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:
(see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
   SELECT TOP(1) PURC_ORDER_LINE.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE, 
   UNIT_PRICE, 
   PURCHASE_ORDER.CURRENCY_ID
   FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE
   LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER
   ON PURC_ORDER_LINE.PURC_ORDER_ID = PURCHASE_ORDER.ID
   WHERE PART_ID = 'some part'
   ORDER BY PURC_ORDER_LINE.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use GROUP BY when you only need TOP 1 and ORDER BY?

```
SELECT TOP 1 LAST_RECEIVED_DATE, 
             UNIT_PRICE, 
             CURRENCY_ID
FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER ON(PURC_ORDER_LINE.PURC_ORDER_ID = PURCHASE_ORDER.ID)
WHERE PART_ID = 'some part'
ORDER BY LAST_RECEIVED_DATE DESC
```

Comment: I now see that Olha had the exact same answer. it seems like this user can use 15 reputation points more then I can use them. Please un-accept my answer and accept Olha's answer instead. you can vote both of these answers up instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652919/sql-select-line-with-most-recent-date/29653167#29653167

Comment: done :) I can't upvote stuff yet though, not enough rep

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT PURC_ORDER_LINE.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE AS [Latest Order]
      ,UNIT_PRICE
      ,PURCHASE_ORDER.CURRENCY_ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PURCHASE_ORDER.CURRENCY_ID 
                 ORDER BY PURC_ORDER_LINE.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE DESC) rn 
FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER
ON PURC_ORDER_LINE.PURC_ORDER_ID = PURCHASE_ORDER.ID
WHERE PART_ID = 'some part'
)
SELECT [Latest Order]
       ,UNIT_PRICE
       ,CURRENCY_ID
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these cases I will get the result set from group by and then join it with the query result set:

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT PURC_ORDER_LINE.PURC_ORDER_ID, MAX(PURC_ORDER_LINE.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE) LRDate
FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE
GROUP BY PURC_ORDER_LINE.PURC_ORDER_ID) Q
JOIN ..... ON condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p1.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE,
    UNIT_PRICE,
    po.CURRENCY_ID
FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PURC_ORDER_ID,MAX(LAST_RECEIVED_DATE) [MaxReceivedDate]
    FROM PURC_ORDER_LINE
    GROUP BY PURC_ORDER_ID
) MaxPur ON MaxPur.[MaxReceivedDate]=p1.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE AND p1.PURC_ORDER_ID=MaxPur.PURC_ORDER_ID
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER po ON p1.PURC_ORDER_ID = po.ID
WHERE PART_ID = 'some part'
GROUP BY UNIT_PRICE, po.CURRENCY_ID
```